# Передача данных между окнами WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу разобраться как правильно передавать данные между окнами в WPF.
Есть главное окно

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public SolidColorBrush colorme = Brushes.Yellow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogBox dia = new DialogBox();
        dia.mymain = this;  <== не хотелось бы делать так
        dia.ShowDialog();
       // colorme = dia.my_solid;
    }
}
```

Оно вызывает диалоговое окно в котором содержится вызов формы для выбора пользователем цвета.

```
public partial class DialogBox : Window
{
    public MainWindow mymain;

    public DialogBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Cnange_Font_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       ColorDialog colorfont = new ColorDialog();
       colorfont.FullOpen = true;
       colorfont.ShowDialog();
       var line = colorfont.Color;
       Color color = Color.FromRgb(line.R, line.G, line.B);
       SolidColorBrush solid = new SolidColorBrush(color);
       mymain.colorme = solid;
    }
}
```

Я насколько понимаю что нежелательно в диалоговое окно передавать ссылку на MainWindow. И есть вариант это сделать через статический класс, но у меня не получается настроить уведомления для MainWindow на произведенные изменения в статическом классе.

Полный мой код.
[Архив](https://office040-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/dzmitry_office040_onmicrosoft_com/Ee_mfeDxU7RIp8YhGZFKWCkBdUayo0G8Z1FH68xjvvvQEg?e=1ng4ym)

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: "через статический класс" абсолютно нежелательно. Передать можно явно или же отгородиться интерфейсом/делегатом, а то и объект посредник (паттерн Mediator/Messenger). Необходиость выделения интерфейса обусловлена "не будем зависеть от реализации", что нужно при тестировании. Но это слой UI, который тестируют как черный ящик (тык по кнопкам), и выделение интерфейса ничего не дает. "статический класс" откровенно плохо, а остальные способы зависят от характера разраба, который может делать как упор на "чистый код наше все", так и на прагматизм "зачем плодить сущности и делать связность косвенной"

Comment: И не стоит забывать про самые обычные события. DialogBox, как и любой другой класс, может иметь event, на которые MainWindow может подписаться.

Comment: Я бы просто внедрил через конструктор делегат, который бы и вызвал по окончании действия или по закрытию диалога.

Answer (score 0):

Не утверждаю, что это самый правильный вариант (понятие "правильно" вообще очень относительно), но я бы сделал так:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public SolidColorBrush ColorMe = Brushes.Yellow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogBox dia = new DialogBox(ColorMe);
        // dia.mymain = this; // <== не хотелось бы делать так
        bool? diaRes = dia.ShowDialog();
        if (diaRes.HasValue && diaRes.Value)
        {
            ColorMe = dia.SelectedColor;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public partial class DialogBox : Window
{
    public SolidColorBrush SelectedColor { get; private set; }

    public DialogBox(SolidColorBrush initialColor)
    {
        SelectedColor = initialColor.Clone();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Cnange_Font_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ColorDialog colorDia = new ColorDialog())
        {
            colorDia.Color
                = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb
                (SelectedColor.Color.A,
                SelectedColor.Color.R,
                SelectedColor.Color.G,
                SelectedColor.Color.B);

            colorDia.FullOpen = true;
            DialogResult res = colorDia.ShowDialog();
            if (res == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.Drawing.Color line = colorDia.Color;
                Color color = Color.FromRgb(line.R, line.G, line.B);
                SelectedColor = new SolidColorBrush(color);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь возможны вариации. Но общий принцип, думаю, понятен. Во вспомогательный диалог передаётся цвет для начального значения, сохраняется внутри в свойстве. После успешного закрытия диалога (не нажата кнопка "отмена", например) считывается новый цвет из этого же свойства.

Comment: Добрый день! Может можете пояснить пару вещей из вашего примера 1) В чем разница между передачей ссылки на объект в диалоговое окно или передачи значения цвета в диалоговое окно, его дальнейшее копирование и присвоению полю ??? 2) Что обозначает данное выражение  if (diaRes.HasValue && diaRes.Value)?  Заранее буду очень благодарен за ответ

Comment: 1) Если вам надо задать в диалоге только цвет - то нет смысла передавать весь объект, только его и передавайте. Также, у вас при этом не будет зависимости реализации DialogBox от реализации MainWindow. Чем проще и независимее данные, которыми обмениваются объекты, тем проще будет понимать работу кода. В моём варианте всё довольно наглядно - во вспомогательный диалог передаётся цвет, который потом используется в основном окне. В вашем варианте непонятно что делается с объектом во вспомогательном диалоге, пока не посмотришь его код.

Comment: 2) Ну это совсем основы. Изучайте Nullable типы - гугл вам в помощь. Window.ShowDialog() как раз возвращает результат в виде Nullable<bool>. Также, смотрите свойство Window.DialogResult. По-хорошему, вы должны задавать это значение внутри кода диалога в зависимости от действий пользователя. Нажал он кнопку "отмена" - диалог вернул false, нажал "OK" - true.